# Remove data.frame rows containing zero, where adjacent rows contain zero

Tags: r

I would like to remove all rows that contain a zero, but only if (the row below it is zero AND the row above it is also zero) OR (it is a zero AND it is the first observation AND the number below it is also a zero).

For example:

```
RowNumb   Column2  
  1          0  
  2          0  
  3          0  
  4          1   
  5          0  
  6          1    
  7          1  
  8          0  
  9          0   
  10         0
```

I would like to remove rows 1, 2, 9 and 10, as these are the only rows that are equal to zero, with a zero below them and either a zero or nothing (in the case of `rowNumb` 1) above them, such that I get the following:

```
RowNumb   Column2  
  3          0  
  4          1   
  5          0  
  6          1    
  7          1  
  8          0
```

Does anyone know of a way of doing this without using a loop?

Comment: or in simpler words, perhaps: "where adjacent rows' values are also zero".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` to sum each absolute value with the preceding and following absolute value and compare that sum with 0:

```
DF <- read.table(text="RowNumb   Column2  
  1          0  
  2          0  
  3          0  
  4          1   
  5          0  
  6          1    
  7          1  
  8          0  
  9          0   
  10         0", header=TRUE)

rem <- na.omit(filter(abs(c(0, DF$Column2, 0)), rep(1, 3)) != 0L)

DF[rem,]
#  RowNumb Column2
#3       3       0
#4       4       1
#5       5       0
#6       6       1
#7       7       1
#8       8       0
```

This assumes there are no `NA` values. If those can occur you'd need to modify this a bit:

```
x <- c(0, DF$Column2, 0)         
rem <- na.omit(filter(x != 0L | is.na(x) , rep(1, 3)) != 0L)
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Could you perhaps explain in greater detail how exactly it works? I just looked up the filter function, but I still don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: With the filter `c(1, 1, 1)` and `sides = 2` the function sums each value with the adjacent values. I need to pad the input with a leading and trailing zero for your special treatment of the first/last row.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `dplyr` approach using `lag` and `lead` functions:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!(Column2 == 0 & lag(Column2, default = 0) == 0 & lead(Column2,default = 0) == 0))
#  RowNumb Column2
#1       3       0
#2       4       1
#3       5       0
#4       6       1
#5       7       1
#6       8       0
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) rollapply** This uses `rollapply` from the zoo package to check if any of three in a row (and because of `partial=TRUE` two in a row at each end) are not zero:

```
library(zoo)

DF[ rollapply(DF$Column2 != 0, 3, any, partial = TRUE), ]
```

giving:

```
  RowNumb Column2
3       3       0
4       4       1
5       5       0
6       6       1
7       7       1
8       8       0
```

**1a)** This variation also works:

```
DF[ rollapply(c(0, DF$Column2, 0) != 0, 3, any), ]
```

**2) embed** This solution does not use any packages.  For this example `embed` forms a 10 x 3 matrix whose rows contain successive triples (two in a row and a zero for rows at the ends) and computes a logical matrix from that and applies `any` to each row:

```
DF[apply(embed(c(0, DF$Column2, 0) != 0, 3), 1, any), ]
```